# Obtaining items in list using BS4 resulting in AttributeError

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm attempting to scrape information from a section of Wikipedia's article for today's date. When I get information from the page using BS4, I am using a method to find the second ul (this corresponds to all text in the "Events" section). I need the text in this section of the article. My current code is the following:

```
time = datetime.now()
day = time.strftime('%B') + '_' + str(int(time.strftime('%d')))
Label(text = 'ON THIS DAY', font = ('Verdana 12 bold')).grid(column = 1, row = 1, in_ = frame2, padx = 10)
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + str(day)
res = requests.get(url)
something = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, features="html.parser")
events = something.find_all('ul')[1]
x = [x.text for x in events]
print(x)
```

The code shown above comes up with the following error from python:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python37\MyScripts\RSSFeed\RSSFeed.py", line 74, in <module>
    load()
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python37\MyScripts\RSSFeed\RSSFeed.py", line 71, in load
    onthisday()
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python37\MyScripts\RSSFeed\RSSFeed.py", line 64, in onthisday
    x = [x.text for x in events]
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python37\MyScripts\RSSFeed\RSSFeed.py", line 64, in <listcomp>
    x = [x.text for x in events]
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 742, in __getattr__
    self.__class__.__name__, attr))
AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'text'
```

I know this error comes from the fact that events is only an item from a list, but how do I fix this?
(BTW, I have looked at the responses in other questions, and all come up with the same error in  mine.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `soup.find_all('ul')[1]`, you're a grabbing that specific element. Once you do that, there's nothing to iterate over, unless you do another `find_all`. You can just convert that whole thing to text, and then split on every new line

```
import requests
import bs4


response = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/January_14')

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

events = soup.find_all('ul')[1]
events_list = events.text.split('\n')

print(events_list)
```

or if you do want to do the list comprehension like you originally planned, you have to find all those tags within `events` (I chose `<li>`) and then you can iterate through those:

```
import requests
import bs4


response = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/January_14')

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

events = soup.find_all('ul')[1]
indv_event = events.find_all('li')

x = [x.text for x in indv_event]
```

So your full code (obviously appears to be more to it, but just for this section should get you going):

```
from datetime import datetime

time = datetime.now()
day = time.strftime('%B') + '_' + str(int(time.strftime('%d')))

# Not too familiar with this line. Looks like for tKinter
Label(text = 'ON THIS DAY', font = ('Verdana 12 bold')).grid(column = 1, row = 1, in_ = frame2, padx = 10)

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + str(day)
res = requests.get(url)

something = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, features="html.parser")

events = something.find_all('ul')[1]
indv_event = events.find_all('li')

x = [x.text for x in indv_event]
print(x)
```